# Get notified when Bitmap is loaded in EaselJS

Tags: canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am building an application with EaselJS, and the app has a background image that is loaded from an S3 bucket, and shapes that are drawn on top of the background.

Right now the shapes appear and then half a second or so later, once the image is loaded, the background appears. I want to delay the appearance of the shapes until after the background image has loaded - is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want? Use PreloadJS and LoadQueue.

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
queue.loadManifest([{id: "myBitmapId", src:'path/to/resource'}]);
queue.on("complete", function() {
   // All assets are now loaded.
  var myBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("myBitmapId"));
  //... continue rendering here
}, this);
```

Comment: You can also just listen for the onload event of an image, or of the `image` property on a Bitmap. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/7nh1q166/